# cron jobs via aws opsworks

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-opsworks

I'm migrating off java web app from GAE to AWS, I have a dozen cron jobs each has a different schedule (one of them has a different timezone), it was quite an easy task @ gae, just appending the servlet & time to execute to the cron.xml file.

I know how to set cron job on linux but I'm guessing aws OpsWorks is better suited for this task, how do I attach a java program to OpsWorks ?
I haven't seen any way to run a command (I used Jenkins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opsworks uses chef for configuration, so you'd need to write a custom chef recipe to manage your crons, there are public cookbooks available where most of it is already automated:

https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/cron

Then you can run your recipe via opsworks.